# Android Studio GCM Registration id shows null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Created Project and got server api key and sender id from https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start .and used following code to generate registration id

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
String   SENDER_ID = "mysenderid";
String Reg_id;
Context context;
EditText firstNumber;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Reg_id=registerGCM();
}
public String registerGCM()
{
    String regid=null;
    try {

        firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regisid_1);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
        firstNumber.setText(regid);
    }
    catch(Exception ae)
    {

    }
    return regid;
}
```

But after executing code ,regid shows null.

Comment: There may be an exception. try printing the exception stack-trace in your catch block..

Comment: result = {String@3816} "java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD"
         count = 32
         hashCode = 0
         offset = 0
         value = {char[41]@3817} 
         shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3428} "class java.lang.String"
         shadow$_monitor_ = -1890400468      . Its shows like this

Comment: By seeing your code I think its a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Please post the full logcat by **editing** your question

Comment: Actually i added these code only. in design added one EditText alone to display registration id. using android emulator. is i have to connect mobile?

Comment: Read this first https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if gcm id is null try to start a background task and get the id.check the below code

```
private void registerInBackground() { 
        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override 
            protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                String msg = "";
                try { 
                    if (gcm == null) { 
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    } 
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID); 
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;


                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend(); 


                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again. 
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid); 
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();


                } 
                return msg;
            } 

            @Override 
            protected void onPostExecute(Object msg) {
//                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n"); 

            } 
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: thanks but how to call it in MainActivity onCreate ?

Comment: call this method from your oncreate--- registerInBackground()